# Javascript Keyup Search of Child Div Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I have a list of tasks that I would like to create a search function for. I have managed to have it so that as soon as you start typing, the list responds and hides all incorrect results. However I am still unable to show the correct result.

Codes are below

**UPDATED WITH CORRECT SOLUTION**

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Player Search" />
<div id="todo">
  <div class="task">Task 1</div>
  <div class="task">Task 2</div>
  <div class="task">Task 3</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var $div = $("#todo")
var result;
$("#search").keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim(this.value).toUpperCase();
  if (val === "")
    $(".task").show()
  else {
    $(".task").hide()
    result = $("#todo .task").filter(function() { //Updated to match child of id todo
      return -1 != $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val)
    }).show()
    console.log(result)
        $(".task").eq(result).show();
  }
})
```

As I have only started learning javascript, I would appreciate if you could explain my errors, and a laymen step-by-step explanation of the answer/process.

As a bonus, if you could also explain how one would troubleshoot a javascript problem like this to find the underlying problem, that would be appreciated.

Comment: why are you missing up vanilla and jquery?

Comment: No particular reason other than it was the only way to get the code to work. I know it's a terrible reason/excuse, but as I said I am trying to learn javascript by doing (doing not so well as you can probably see).

Comment: i will point out a few things i notice: **ID should always be unique**; filter the child of element with id todo not element with todo

Comment: Thanks. It is now logging the correct result based on what I type, however if I understand my code correctly, on correct match it is showing the element todo rather than child of element with id todo (same problem as you mentioned). How do I do .parent().child().show() -- I know that is incorrect, but something to that effect.

Comment: i cant say much unless you share the js you used and html you can update the OP anyway

Comment: OP have been updated

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/7sfr49px/) check this demo [updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/7sfr49px/1/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111719/discussion-between-guradio-and-ryan-n).

Comment: Thanks mate. Your original demo was close, but had some issues - only showing the first result even if there were multiple matches. I have played with your code and found the solution per my updated OP. Cheers for your help!

Comment: i updated the code see the updated code. by the way there are many ways to this not just this one. i will put it in answer and explain as much as i can would that be ok?

Comment: Of course. Would be happy to continue learning different solutions to the same problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var $div = $("#todo")
var result;
$("#search").keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim(this.value).toUpperCase();
  if (val === "")
    $div.show()
  else {
    $(".task").hide()
    result = $("#todo .task").filter(function() { //Updated to match child of id todo
      return -1 != $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val)
    }).index()//get the index of the div that has match
    console.log(result)
        result != -1 ? $(".task").eq(result).show() : $(".task").hide()//show or hide div depending on matching index
  }
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/7sfr49px/1/)

1. Always remember **ID should always be unique** in same context.
2. Use class to target multiple elements.

Comment: Thanks mate. I appreciate the help, especially the general insight on how best to code. However I still think your code needs tweaking as I explained. If you try my code, you can see the difference I'm talking about. Nevertheless, thank you for helping me solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
function SearchContactInGroup(Strtext) {

            $('#userchat_grouping .name').each(function () {

                if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(Strtext.toLowerCase())>= 0) {


                    $(this).closest('li').show('slow');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).closest('li').hide('slow');
                }
            });
            // $('#dvLoading').hide();
        }



    $(window).load(function () {
     $('#txtsearch').keyup(function () {
     SearchContactInGroup($(this).val());
   });});
```